# NFSv4 java client: read files in shared folder

Tags: java, client, nfs

[Preconditions]
I have NFSv4 fileshare running on RHEL, and I can successfully mount shared folder on another RHEL machine and see it's content (Thus configuration seems fine).

[PROBLEM]
I would like to also read shared folder from java client code on Windows (without mounting file share anywhere) but currently no success.

[WHAT I'VE TRIED]
Tried [YANFS](https://java.net/projects/yanfs)  but it only supports NFSv2 and NFSv3; also there's [dCache](https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j) library but it looks like it mostly NFS server (However I've looked through it, it has some client classes but I did not succeed in reading remote file share with it).

[QUESTION]
How to read remote NFSv4 shared folder from java client without mounting?

Comment: looking for the same, either Java or C#.
did you find a solution for this?

Comment: May be this will help https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j, But it required java 11